# Activate Workbook WITHOUT filename but using the extension

Tags: excel, vba

I have slowly learning some VBA by searching them through google, this site has the best format for understanding the answers. I have been able to really automate many of my reports but have hit a wall in searching out this function.

I have a many reports and we use a web interface to generate specific data. the file names are always randomly generated when exported, but they are always (read only) .xls files.

I have tried other VBA commands that i have searched heavily but none work. using the "*.xls" doesnt seem to work. these have no file path, but are the only .xls workbook open when running this report.

I would appreciate any assistance.

Comment: Sorry, but me it is unclear what you want to archive or what you are asking

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to SO.

In your question you say *have no file path, but **are the only .xls workbook open** when running this report.*

If this is true (the .xls workbook you want is the ONLY one opened at this time), then this code may work for you.

It will loop trough each opened workbook and check the extension of the file. If it is XLS then it will activate it.

```
Dim f As FileSystemObject

Set f = New FileSystemObject

    Dim WB As Workbook

    For Each WB In Application.Workbooks
        If f.GetExtensionName(WB.FullName) = "xls" Then
            WB.Activate
            'rest of your code
        End If
    Next WB

    Set f = Nothing
```

To make this code work, you need to activate a reference:

In the VBA Editor, go to TOOLS-> REFERENCES and search for **Microsoft Scripting Runtime**

[image]

Hope this can help you